# WSDL & .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, wsdl

We connect to Salesforce via their SOAP api and it works great in .NET Framework. However, in .NET Core, when we apply the WSDL to generate a reference class, it uses System.Web and that won't work in .NET Core.

Is there a way to generate a reference/binding class for a SOAP WSDL that works in .NET Core?

Comment: I am also having issue connecting a WSDL file, did you find a solution?

Comment: No. Pushed this question up several levels at Salesforce support, no solution.